# How to inject value from server side to client side?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm rendering an angular app on the server and I'm trying to inject a string value to my service, it works fine on the server but on the browser the value is null. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

server.ts:

```
renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
  // Our index.html
  document: template,
  url: options.req.url,
  // DI so that we can get lazy-loading to work differently (since we need it to just instantly render it)
  extraProviders: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
    {provide: "clientIp", useValue: "129.112.28.171", deps: []}
  ]
})
```

Service:

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GeoService {
    constructor(@Inject("clientIp") @Optional() protected clientIp: string) {
   // clientIp is "129.112.28.171" on the server but null on the client/browser
   }
}
```

How can I access the value on the browser?

Comment: `@Inject("clientIp")` is not a valid injection token. See: https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken

Comment: `How can I access the value on the browser?` you can not *transmit* data to the front-end via the `renderModuleFactory`. It doesn't work that way. You have to perform a HTTP request to read data.

Comment: @Reactgular Turns out this is a job for TransferState service and not DI. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: You if know of a way to do this, then please post an answer and tag me. I'd like to read more.